# Why is subdivision surface behaving like this?

Tags: subdivision-surface, 3d-printing

I'm wanting to 3D print my object- so I'm looking for a literal way of smoothing.. I want this object physically smooth while maintaining creases and negative space, like this:
[image: (autosmoothing and smooth shaded to show example)]

However, Subdivision surface is behaving like this. Why? And how do I fix it?
[image]

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

This will happen if you don't have enough geometry on the large faces with the cut-out to support the subdivision operation.  Consider these two objects:  both have the same shape cut out of a flat disk, but on the left, only a few edges have been used to connect the cut-out to the outside of the disk, while on the right, the same shape has been cut out of a whole grid of geometry:

[image]

and here's what they look like with a subdivision surface modifier added:

[image]

Note that the geometry doesn't have to be perfect.  Even pretty crude geometry will usually work:

[image]

You'll need to add a similar amount of geometry on the faces with your heart cut-out.  The heart shape might make it a little harder.  At the sharp parts of the curve, you make find it necessary to introduce duplicate overlapping or nearly overlapping edges:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much that makes total sense!! I think it was the underside giving me trouble.. I got lazy and filled the whole thing in one big section, rather than individual pieces. Learnt my lesson lol

Answer (score 0):

A method I found to fix this (this isn't the 'right' way of doing it albeit- but posting to potentially help anyone else!)..

1. alt+click the section of edge you want (in my case, the heart)
2. shift+D to duplicate
3. Press P and choose the new object from the top-right menu
4. fill it, extrude it upwards and create a boolean on the original object with it
5. use subdivision surface! (It won't fill in the hole because of the boolean :)